# Perform rowwise non-vectorized function on a combination of columns in a data.table (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rowwise

I have a very large data.table in R (~200,000) entries, and I want to perform a **non-vectorized function to each row**. This function needs inputs from two columns of this data.table. The value of one column is linked to another list with each member containing ~1,000,000 numbers. Here is a simplified case with `mtcars`

```
#setup a fake list for my function call    
gears <- mtcars %>% arrange(gear) %>% pull(gear) %>% unique
gear_lst <- lapply(gears, function(x){rnorm(1000000, mean = x**2, sd = x*2)}) %>% setNames(.,gears)  

#make a mega data table     
mega_mtcars <- sapply(mtcars, rep.int, times = 10000) %>% as.data.table

#this is the function I want to call    
my_function <- function(x,y){
    sum(x > gear_lst[[y]])
}

# rowwise call is low
out <- mega_mtcars %>% mutate(gear_c = as.character(gear)) %>% rowwise %>% mutate(out = my_function(mpg, gear_c))
```

One thing I tried is to add a nested column of `gear_lst` for each `gear` entry, so that I would be able to perform vectorized function. However, because the list is large, the memory failed to created such a data structure.

**Update**:
@akrun provided a few ways, I wasn't able to test them with my original mega_mtcars because it's too big.  I sized it down 100 fold and here is the performance so far (it doesn't seem any improvement over the original rowwise method):

```
#make a smaller mega_mtcars
mega_mtcars <- sapply(mtcars, rep.int, times = 100) %>% as.data.table

# use rowwise from dplyr
system.time(mega_mtcars %>% rowwise %>% mutate(out = my_function(mpg, as.character(gear))))
   user  system elapsed 
  8.086   2.860  10.941 
    
# use Map with data.table
system.time(mega_mtcars[, out := unlist(Map(my_function, x = mpg, y = as.character(gear)))])
  user  system elapsed 
  7.843   2.815  10.654 
    
# use dapply from collapse package
system.time(dapply(mega_mtcars[, .(mpg, gear)], MARGIN = 1, function(x) my_function(x[1], as.character(x[2]))))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.957   3.167  11.127
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: would you mind to add `julia` tag to your post? I recently found about the language and like to see how vectorized computation is compared to fast loop.

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table`, `rowwise` can be achieved by grouping over the row sequence

```
library(data.table)
mega_mtcars[, out := my_function(mpg, as.character(gear)) , 
       by = 1:nrow(mega_mtcars)]
```

Comment: This is really great @akrun and motivates me to explore `data.table` more. With my tries it was not possible!

Comment: @TarJae you may also use `Map` here i.e `Map(my_function, x = mpg, y = as.character(gear))` without the grouping

Comment: This is interesting, but it doesn't seem be faster than rowwise method. Am I wrong?

Comment: @coffee it wouldn't be because both are doing similar things.  If you want to make it faster, try with `Map` i.e. `mega_mtcars[, out := unlist(Map(my_function, x = mpg, y = as.character(gear))]`

Comment: @akrun it performs the same, unfortunately

Comment: @coffee then you may need `dapply` from `collapse` i.e. `dapply(mega_mtcars[, .(mpg, gear)], MARGIN = 1, function(x) my_function(x[1], as.character(x[2])))`  which is a bit more optimized for rowwise operations

Comment: @akrun, still not better. I have updated the original post with the benchmark from your suggestions.

Comment: @coffee rowwise operations are time consuming.  You may split into chunks and do a parallel operations

Comment: @coffee Also, the `as.character` step can be outside ie. `mega_mtcars[, gear := as.character(gear)]` so that we don't have to convert to character in each iteration

Comment: @coffee based on your updated example data, a `for` loop timing is better `system.time({
out <- numeric(nrow(mega_mtcars));
mega_mtcars[, gear := as.character(gear)];
for(i in seq_along(out)) {
  out[i] <- my_function(mega_mtcars$mpg[i], mega_mtcars$gear[i])
    }
})`

Comment: @akrun, I guess I will have to look into parallel processing. I've used `multidplyr`before, but it doesn't work with `rowwise`.

Comment: @akrun using dev version even enables `mega_mtcars[, out := my_function(mpg, as.character(gear)), by=.I]` now ;)

Comment: @Ben373 thanks, does it improves the efficiency when you use `.I`

Comment: @akrun nah only plays more nicely together when you also select with `DT[i, ]` than `1:nrow(DT)`.

Answer (score -1):

does sorting the values in gear_lst help?

Comment: I guess it might, but I doubt it would help much because `my_function` is a vectorized operation and it's very fast.

Comment: i see, then I guess just run the naive one, because the running time should be around 10.94 * 100 = 1094 seconds

Comment: But my real dataset as well as the computation is more complicated than this, and it's taking forever.